# How to Run dotnet app on Linux Unbuntu automatically restarting via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, .net-core

I have a dotnet Server Application that i start like this to run it even when the console is closed.
`nohup dotnet app.dll --urls=http://adress/ &`

i want to create a bash script that restarts it infinite by itself when it has some issue and breaks and found some solution here like this:

`while true; do ./app && break; done`

I tried to encapsulate my code like this.

`while true; do nohup dotnet app.dll --urls=http://adress/ & && break; done`

which does not work because of the & && (the first & is a configuration for nohup)
Then i tried to create just a second bash script and run it like this.

while true;
do ./secondbashscript && break;
done

While the second bash script consists of the nohup dotnet line.

But i had some trouble to get it running and i don't want to be stuck in an infinite loop which i expect. Instead it should just start the dotnet application and restart it but don't start it more than once at a time.

Comment: just run `while true; do dotnet app.dll --urls=http://adress/; done` in a [tag:gnu-screen] or [tag:tmux] window.

Comment: if i do that, can i still close the application, because normally the Loop would prevent this without && break.

Comment: do u mean the terminal app by "application"? yes the terminal can be closed. gnu-screen/tmux will keep running in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the tool `Supervisor` will help you with this.
The tool can refer the [docs](http://supervisord.org/running.html#adding-a-program).

And I also find a [blog](https://www.cnblogs.com/along21/p/10255681.html) teach how to create a daemon process for a dotnet app.

Comment: Hey Gary. I found out that a daemon process is a better fit. But the Process like this still throws some errors when running. Started manually it works fine but as deamon it breaks after some time.

Comment: Hi @CamouflagedPenguin, Did you print the logs and what is the error reported? Where is it not as expected? I see that your configuration `RestartSec=86400` is too long, more details will help me understand the "breaks" better. And I found a [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnetcore/practice-troubleshoot-linux/2-3-configure-aspnet-core-application-start-automatically) wish will help.

Comment: Hey Gary, i just did a typo and now it works most of the time. There are still some issues but those are  not related to the demon process but to the app i am running. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a solution better fit for my problem than using Screen or tools like this and if i understand it right is should run without console running. Otherwise i still need to detach it.

i create a service using systemd in the /etc/systemd/system/ directory with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Application

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/application
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /path/to/your/application/Application.dll --urls=http://:*/
Restart=always
RestartSec=86400

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```